# Input stream error when partially deserializing derived class into base class using Boost

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

When I serialize a derived class using boost and try to deserialize only the base part, I get input stream error. I guess my code is wrong. Is there a way to deserialize only the base part of a derived object using boost archive? 
Reason for this code is that I am trying to implement a design to send derived objects from one process to another. The receiving process will look at the ID in the base part to decide which derived object is received.

This is the test code with which I am trying to verify that this is possible using boost, but I get input stream error on executing this

```
class DataIface
{
 public:
DataIface()
:num(0)
{
}
DataIface( int num):
    num(num)
{
}
int num;
template< class Archive >
    void serialize( Archive& ar, const unsigned int version )
    {
        std::cout<<"Serializing base class \n"<<std::endl;
        ar & num;
    }
};

class Data1 : public DataIface
{
private:
friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
Data1()
:a(0)
{

};
Data1( int a, int num):
    DataIface(num),
    a(a)
{

}
int a;
template< class Archive >
void serialize( Archive& ar, const unsigned int version )
{
    std::cout<<"Serializing derived class \n"<<std::endl;
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<DataIface>(*this);
    ar & a;

}

};

int main()
{
Data1 obj(10, 20);
std::ostringstream oss;
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa( oss );

oa << obj;

Data1 obj2;

std::istringstream iss(oss.str());
boost::archive::text_iarchive ia( iss );

ia >> obj2;

cout<< obj2.a << std::endl;
cout << obj2.num << std::endl;

DataIface iface;
try
{
 ia >> iface;
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout<<e.what()<<std::endl;
}
cout << iface.num << std::endl;



return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> This is the test code that I am trying to verify that this is possible using boost and I get input stream error

What is the conclusion?

The conclusion is: it doesn't work. That's because it's not a feature. No where in the documentation does it even suggest you can do this.

### Runtime Polymorphism

Just use polymorphism as intended!

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27d4a043ba61dd94)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

class DataIface {
  public:
    virtual ~DataIface() {}
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
};

class Data1 : public DataIface {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

  public:
    Data1(int a=0) : a(a) {}
    int a;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        ar &boost::serialization::base_object<DataIface>(*this);
        ar &a;
    }
};

class Data2 : public DataIface {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

  public:
    Data2(int b=0) : b(b) {}
    int b;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        ar &boost::serialization::base_object<DataIface>(*this);
        ar &b;
    }
};


BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Data1)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Data2)

int main() {

    DataIface* tests[] = { new Data1(10), new Data2(-10) };

    for(auto testobj : tests)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        {
            boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);

            oa << testobj;
        }

        {
            std::istringstream iss(oss.str());
            boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss);

            DataIface* obj = nullptr;
            ia >> obj;

            if (Data1* obj1 = dynamic_cast<Data1*>(obj))
                std::cout << "It's a Data1: " << obj1->a << "\n";
            if (Data2* obj2 = dynamic_cast<Data2*>(obj))
                std::cout << "It's a Data2: " << obj2->b << "\n";
        }
    }

    for(auto ptr : tests) delete ptr;
}
```

Prints:

```
void Data1::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]
void DataIface::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]
void Data1::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]
void DataIface::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]
It's a Data1: 10
void Data2::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]
void DataIface::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]
void Data2::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]
void DataIface::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]
It's a Data2: -10
```

---

### Static Polymorphism

Alternatively, use a variant. This saves you the hassle of manual dynamic allocations and the potential cost of virtual dispatch.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d0d3233168c36c6)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/variant.hpp>

class Data1 {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

  public:
    Data1(int a=0) : a(a) {}
    int a;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar &a;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Data1 const& d) {
        return os << "It's a Data1: " << d.a;
    }
};

class Data2 {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

  public:
    Data2(int b=0) : b(b) {}
    int b;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar &b;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Data2 const& d) {
        return os << "It's a Data2: " << d.b;
    }
};

int main() {

    using V = boost::variant<Data1, Data2>;
    V tests[] = { Data1{10}, Data2{-10} };

    for(auto testobj : tests)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        {
            boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);
            oa << testobj;
        }

        {
            std::istringstream iss(oss.str());
            boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss);

            V deserialized;
            ia >> deserialized;

            std::cout << deserialized << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
It's a Data1: 10
It's a Data2: -10
```